# List all files in directory and make it navigatable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, treeview, erb

In my public/ I have a log folder, which contains others folders.
These folders by its time contains some files.

What I want to do is make this log folder accessible to public in a way that they cant click in the sub-folders name and see whats inside, being able to open the .txt files.

My structure is like this:

```
- public
   - log
     1. element1
        - file1.txt
        - file2.txt
     2. element2
        - file1.txt
        - file2.txt
```

I haven't found a way to do this. I came close with this piece of code:

```
<ul>
    <% Dir.entries("public/log/girlbcn")[2..-1].each do |file_name| 
      <li><%= link_to file_name, "/#{URI.escape(file_name)}" %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

But it would not let me navigate though the structure nor open files (I think it is because of the routes config, which I don't have much knowledge about)

I'm using Rails 4.1.2

Comment: I'm not sure it's such a good idea to give users such access to your server. Nevertheless, if I were you I'd probably explore javascript based solutions for this. See this link for example: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/file-browser-with-jstree-angularjs-and-expressjs/

Comment: @DaniG2k it is an administrative system, therefore only the admin will be able to access this page.  Do you have any better idea to show him the logs?